# How to get custom options value in Xcode 8 iOS project wizard?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I have created the custom ios project template and I have added name, email and mobile options added in Choose options for your project wizard and they are required for project creation(PFA). How to get those option values after project creation.

[image: Custom project template wizard]

TemplateInfo.plist :

```
    <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Kind</key>
    <string>Xcode.Xcode3.ProjectTemplateUnitKind</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.test</string>
    <key>Ancestors</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.dt.unit.storyboardApplication</string>
        <string>com.apple.dt.unit.coreDataCocoaTouchApplication</string>
    </array>
    <key>Concrete</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>This template provides a starting point for an application that uses a single view. It provides a view controller to manage the view, and a storyboard or nib file that contains the view.</string>
    <key>SortOrder</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>Options</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>Description</key>
            <string>Name.</string>
        <key>EmptyReplacement</key> 
            <string>Name</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>Name</string>
        <key>Name</key>
            <string>Name</string>
        <key>NotPersisted</key>
            <true/>
        <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
        <key>Type</key>
            <string>text</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Description</key>
            <string>Email address.</string>
        <key>EmptyReplacement</key> 
            <string>Email</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>Email</string>
        <key>Name</key>
            <string>Email</string>
        <key>NotPersisted</key>
            <true/>
        <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
        <key>Type</key>
            <string>text</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Description</key>
            <string>Mobile number.</string>
        <key>EmptyReplacement</key> 
            <string>Mobile</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>Mobile</string>
        <key>Name</key>
            <string>Mobile</string>
        <key>NotPersisted</key>
            <true/>
        <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
        <key>Type</key>
            <string>text</string>
    </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>languageChoice</string>
            <key>Units</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Swift</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Nodes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>AppDelegate.swift</string>
                        <string>ViewController.swift</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Definitions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Base.lproj/Main.storyboard</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>Main.storyboard</string>
            <key>SortOrder</key>
            <integer>99</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>AppDelegate.swift</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>AppDelegate.swift</string>
        </dict>
        <key>ViewController.swift</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>ViewController.swift</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Could you post the template file you used for this?

Comment: I have added TemplateInfo.plist

Comment: I've had a look and I can't work it out. There's a real lack of online documentation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<key>Identifier</key>
<string>name</string>
```

The custom option value will be created in this format **___VARIABLE_identifier___**.
You can get the **name** options value using this **___VARIABLE_name___**